# How to run a 60-seconds signal in real time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am doing a simulation of the lungs on Unity. I have a signal of the volume that control my lung object which is sampled for 60 seconds. When I run it, it finishes the entire signal in few seconds. However, I need the simulation to be in real-time and run for the entire 60 seconds. I don't want to run it in slow motion because it doesn't look  realistic.

```
private int i = 0;                  // initialize  iterator
void Update()
{
 if (i < MainFlow.Length)
 {
  float f = (float)MainFlow[i];    // value of current volume
  float k = f + 2.5f;              // adding initial volume
  transform.localScale = new Vector3(k, k, k);
  i++;          
 }
 else
 {  
  i = 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: From what I gather you have sample data, but the frequency of that is lower than your simulation and thus it either runs too fast or looks very laggy. In that case; interpolate between sample points?

Comment: exactly. but I already have 1500 samples which run in 26 seconds, then I need to double my samples. Also I don't know exactly the frequency of the simulation, and I need to be exact in timing.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try to double secondsPerSample to see if it really takes double the time? Edit: Oops, meant to comment instead of adding another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to know the framerate of your simulation. If it's 1500 samples in 60 seconds, that's presumably 25Hz. You can then sample two of the MainFlow values each frame and interpolate between them to produce a smooth output.

Something like this:

```
float frequency = 25.0f;
float simulationTime = Time.time * frequency;
int firstFrameIndex = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.FloorToInt(simulationTime), 0, MainFlow.length);
int secondFrameIndex = Mathf.Clamp(firstFrameIndex + 1, 0, MainFlow.length);
float fraction = simulationTime - firstFrameIndex;
float sample1 = (float)MainFlow[firstFrameIndex];
float sample2 = (float)MainFlow[secondFrameIndex];
float k = Mathf.Lerp(sample1, sample2, fraction) + 2.5f;
transform.localScale = new Vector3(k, k, k);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood your concept, but where do you get this "frame1". Also is it ok for sample1 and sample2 to be float?

Comment: Hi @OmarMoussa - they were both typos. I've corrected them.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is frame rate dependent, the more fps you get, the faster the simulation will be.

I would instead start a coroutine to have more control. Let's say MainFlow contains 1200 samples for a total of 60s, this means the sample rate is 20 Hz (samples/second). So you should process 20 samples per second or in other words, 1 sample per 1/20 second.

So:

```
private float secondsPerSample;

private void Start()
{
    float sampleRate = MainFlow.Length / 60f;
    secondsPerSample = 1 / sampleRate;
    StartCoroutine(Process());
}

private IEnumerator Process()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MainFlow.Length; i++)
    {
        float f = (float) MainFlow[i]; // value of current volume
        float k = f + 2.5f; // adding initial volume
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(k, k, k); i++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsPerSample);
    }

    yield return Process();
}
```

Edit: My answer will run the simulation exactly like it is sampled. If you want to interpolate it instead, eAi's answer will probably help you.

Comment: **Note!** [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) is still affected by the `Time.timeScale`. You should rather use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) in this case

Comment: Good thing to note but I think things like this **should** be affected by the time scale.

Comment: not neccesarily if OP explicitely says he wants 60 seconds in real-time

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but the sampleRate should be MainFlow.Lenght/ 60. In my case (samples=1500, Freq=25Hz) the secondsPerSample= 0.04. which is mathematically correct (1500*0.04=60). However, the simulation is still running only in 37s with WaitForSeconds and 38s with WaitForSecondsRealtime.
Also, thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Weird, are you doing it exactly like the snipped I posted?

Comment: I did. I printed the time difference between each loop and it's 0.05 (I'm guessing delay+processing time), but still it goes over in 37 seconds

Comment: Actually it's very weird. I tried different values. 0.004 yielded with 37 seconds and 0.068 yielded with 61 seconds.